# How does the fetchNext(int) method works in jooq?

Tags: jooq

From the documentation of fetchNext(int number) - 
"This will conveniently close the Cursor, after the last Record was fetched."

Assuming number=100 and there are 1000 records in total.
Will it close the cursor once the 100th record was fetched, or when the 1000th was fetched? 
In other words, what is the "last record" referred in the documentation?

```
Cursor<Record> records = dsl.select...fetchLazy();

while (records.hasNext()) {
   records.fetchNext(100).formatCSV(out);
}
out.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This convenience is a historic feature in jOOQ, which will be removed eventually: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8884. As with every `Closeable` resource in Java, you should *never* rely on this sort of auto closing. It is always better to eagerly close the resource when you *know* you're done using it. In your case, ideally, wrap the code in a try-with-resources statement.

What the Javadoc means is that the underlying JDBC `ResultSet` will be closed as soon as jOOQ's call to `ResultSet.next()` yields `false`, i.e. the database returns no more records. So, no. If there are 1000 records in total from your select, and you're only fetching 100, then the cursor will not be closed. If it were, this wouldn't be a "convenience feature", but break all sorts of other API, including the one you've called. It's totally possible to call `fetchNext(100)` twice, or in a loop, as you did.

Comment: Thanks, indeed we were expecting it to be closed only after the last of all records was fetched (hasNext==false).
I was asking because recently we encountered a performance degradation and in some cases even partial results since we have transitioned from recreating the DSLContext on every DB call to creating it once and reusing it. Please find the code example in the EDIT above.

Comment: @Hagai: Thanks for your update. I'm not sure if that's related. Would you mind reverting your edit and asking a new question instead? Future visitors of this question will probably find it more useful if the two questions are separated.

Comment: Sure, reverted and created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57875498/performance-degradation-when-reusing-dslcontext-in-jooq