# Performance degradation when reusing DSLContext in jooq

Tags: jooq

Recently we encountered a performance degradation and in some cases even partial results, once we have transitioned from recreating the DSLContext on every call to creating it once and reusing it. Practically we transitioned from this -

```
  //Method call  
  try (Connection c = dataSource.getConnection()) {
          DSLContext dsl = DSL.using(c);
          return dsl.select().from(view).where(condition).fetchSize(1000).fetchLazy();
        }
```

to this -

```
//Ctor
this.dsl = DSL.using(dataSource, SQLDialect.DEFAULT);

//Method call  
dsl.select().from(view).where(condition).getQuery().fetchSize(1000).fetchLazy();
```

Was hoping to get some lead what could cause this.

Comment: What database product are you using? What is `view`?

Comment: Oracle, view is a a non-materlialized view.

Comment: Why not use `SQLDialect.ORACLE`, instead? What's the complete generated SQL query in each case (you can all `Query.getSQL()` on each query, or look into your debug logs. What kind of performance degradation are we talking about? Can you give some numbers, profiling results, execution plans, etc.?

Comment: We're using the free version, I don't see ```SQLDialect.ORACLE``` available.
Generated query in both cases is ```select * from view where config_id=123 or config_id is NULL.```
Regarding performance, what I see is that up to fetchSize(=1000) results are returning fine, but when the next batch executes it seems to get stuck and usually results in a timeout.
I'll try to extract execution plans.

Comment: I recommend upgrading to the jOOQ Professional Edition. The jOOQ Open Source Edition does not support Oracle. Anyway, in this case, that's not the performance issue. I can't think of what it could be though, and I doubt the difference you're experiencing is jOOQ related. There's no difference from the jOOQ perspective in the two approaches. jOOQ calls `DataSource.getConnection()` and `Connection.close()` just the same...

Comment: Thank @LukasEder. We will look into upgrading while we continue the research on what could cause this.